# What format is this structure? What is its name/type?

Tags: file, file-format, dataformat

I need to parse files. This structure is unknown to me. Is this structure a well-known format? Does it have a name?

```
datatype1 (
    name "foo file list"
    description "desc foo file list"
    version 20151224-170000
    comment "no comment"
)

datatype2 (
    name "TEST1"
    description "desc of TEST1"
    file ( name "test1.foo" size 256 crc 39C9812E md5 51af2f29e86e1234e64f42e3a385753e sha1 1AD31EAAB0B175BB999C0EB5DF3D193DA822229F )
)


datatype2 (
    name "TEST2"
    description "desc of TEST2"
    file ( name "test2.foo" size 256 crc 39C9812E md5 51af2f29e86e1234e64f42e3a385753e sha1 1AD31EAAB0B175BB999C0EB5DF3D193DA822229F )
)
```

Comment: That looks like LISP data structure

Comment: At the moment, you should concentrate on figuring out the file format, which means it has nothing to do with Ruby. When you find out the format, then ask a different question as a Ruby question.

Comment: There is no LISP. LISP is a programming language. LISP is not a data structure. They look similar only because of the brackets. The syntax is very different.